# Rep-Capped, Keeps Answering

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers, daily-reputation-limit

I hit the rep-cap today (+230, including 2 checkmarks, no bounties), and then I answered an interesting question that I couldn't help but answer anyway. As "lost rep" from the upvotes started accumulating, a thought occurred to me:

> *If I delete this answer now, and un-delete it after midnight UTC, would I get the upvotes back?*

I don't want to try it because I feel like it would be somewhat "gaming the system" and at the end of the day it's just +20 (well, at the time of this writing), but I really honestly wonder, how would that be handled by the system?

---

> Possibility 1

My daily rep goes to +210 upon deleting; the two upvotes that didn't count upwards suddenly count downwards. That'd be somewhat awkward, but I'd understand. Midnight UTC I un-delete the answer and get the +20 back. Net change: 0.

---

> Possibility 2

My daily rep doesn't move upon deleting, because the two upvotes didn't count upwards and won't count downwards. Midnight UTC I un-delete the answer and get a free +20. Net change: +20, and I just gamed the rep-cap.

---

How does that actually work?

Comment: I *hope*, and believe, that it's `Possibility 1`.

Comment: @ShadowWizard sorry about that - I just cast a close/dupe vote on my own question :) ...or should I just delete it?

Comment: No don't delete, having dupes is useful for easier search.

Comment: Votes on deleted posts are handled *as if the votes were never cast*. **Undeleting** again makes those votes 'reappear'; e.g. *they reappear on the same day they were cast*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you delete the answer, your reputation will be recalculated as if the post never existed, meaning you will receive the reputation on other qualifying upvotes for the day instead, since you now didn't gain anything from those ones.

Upon undeleting, the same exact process ensues. Your reputation is recalculated as if that post had existed all along. If votes on that post counted originally, they will begin to count again and the reputation from the upvotes that replaced it upon deletion will stop counting.

You would not lose out on any reputation while it was deleted, and you would not "game" any additional reputation upon undeleting it.

Comment: No client side check on mobile theme? Good for you! :)